# What's bad with this short, direct question?

Tags: discussion

I really miss what's wrong with this question in it's current form:

[Is terminal output duplicated or just appended from stdout and stderr devices?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480582/is-terminal-output-duplicated-or-just-appended-from-stdout-and-stderr-devices)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea what that question is asking, which is also what the people who closed it indicated. Can you rephrase it somehow?

Comment: Is this better now?...